# Rhyming Riddle: Some are found through start and gates

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> Some are found through start and gates,
>
> Some are born of carbonates.
>
> Something employment likely hates,
>
> You'll have to reach to activate.
>
> Allow a star to penetrate,
>
> With colour added they fascinate.

**What might I be?**

...

EDIT:
**An extra clue...**

> Sometimes I'm blinded by those that can see,
>
> Sometimes it's hard to even see me.

Comment: A down vote with no comment. Sometimes I don't really get this site :(

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Because they can, I guess.

Comment: dont worry, there is no downvote right now

Comment: The clues are quite cryptic especially at the start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't make everything work, but maaaybe you are a

> window.

Some are found through start and gates,

> *Microsoft* Windows. (*Bill* Gates.)

Some are born of carbonates.

> Polycarbonate plastic (not as nice as glass, but e.g. it's what the windows of my shed are made of).

Something employment likely hates,

> I don't have a good explanation for this. (Maybe some employers don't like the idea of their employees sitting at their desks gazing out of the window instead of working hard?)

You'll have to reach to activate.

> Opening windows high up in the wall can be something of a stretch.

Allow a star to penetrate,

> Windows are transparent and you can see the sky through them.

With colour added they fascinate.

> Stained glass windows?

Sometimes I'm blinded by those that can see,

> Blinded = having a blind attached.

Sometimes it's hard to even see me.

> Again, windows are transparent. (As birds sometimes discover to their cost.)

Comment: You got it! Well done! :D

Comment: The "employment likely hates" was a bit of a tedious link. It was employment = jobs = Steve = Steve Jobs. He likely doesn't like Windows as he was a Mac lover lol.

Comment: Carbonates referred to Sodium Carbonate which is commonly used in windows. Polycarbonate works even better! :)

Comment: Start was a reference to the "start menu"."Allow a star to penetrate" simply meant let the sunlight in too.

Comment: Jobs! D'oh. And I should have thought of sodium carbonate. (Yes, I got the start menu bit. The reason I didn't call it out specifically as I did for Bill Gates was that I thought it was more obvious :-).)

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> Switch

Some are found through start and gates,

> You use switch to start something. Simple combination of logic gates are used as switches.

Some are born of carbonates

> It seems like Switch is a carbonated drink brand. http://www.foodbev.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/14/switch-juice-drinks.jpg

Something employment likely hates,

> The employers dont like if you switch from their company. Hassle for employees too.

You'll have to reach to activate.

> You need to reach out to click on the switches. Say to turn on the fan.

Allow a star to penetrate,

> Switch Star seems like a gameplay element in Super Mario Bros. http://www.mariowiki.com/Star_Switch

With colour added they fascinate.

> Color switch is a very famous game. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fortafygames.colorswitch&hl=en

Comment: Good guess but it's not what I was going for. :)

Comment: That one crossed my mind, but I couldn't come up with links for half the clues. Nicely done even if it wasn't right!

Answer (score 1):

Is it:

> An access card?

Some are found through start and gates,

> That's what they are used for

Some are born of carbonates.

> Could be plastic or paper

Something employment likely hates,

> This is far fetched by assuming that actually the word should be employees - and if there is a time monitoring system based on access card, then yes, employees will hate it.

You'll have to reach to activate.

> you have to reach to the the card reader

Allow a star to penetrate,

> not sure about this one

With colour added they fascinate.

> The could be colourful

What might I be?

Comment: Interesting guess but it's not the one. All the clues slot in nicely when the right answer is found. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be

> Fireworks

Some are found through start and gates,
Some are born of carbonates.

> Fireworks are used for start a celebration like the the new year (who is at the gate).

Something employment likely hates,
You'll have to reach to activate.

> Of course you have to light the fuse in order to activate them.

Allow a star to penetrate,
With colour added they fascinate.

> They usually draw colorful stars.

Comment: I like your thinking but it's not the one. I added some new hints that might help out a bit more. :)